# Transactional code in Korma with multiple databases

Tags: clojure

Is it possible to use the transaction macro in [Korma](http://sqlkorma.com/) when multiple databases are used inside? I tried so, but then it picks just a single database and binds all queries and clauses to that.

*EDIT*

My use case is somekind of ETL and since I do only readonly tasks from the source it would be ok to have only one transactions which affects the target db.

Answer (score 2):

Using a single DB per transaction is somewhat baked into Korma (and most any other similar system).  When using multiple DBs, hence having more than one transaction, it seems that you would need an additional layer of abstraction forcibly aborts one transaction if the other fails. If you don't do it too often its likely fine to do these checks by hand, though I would not hold out for any DBMS to handle it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I updated my question a little bit to be more clear. Having a single transaction wrapping multiple databases is not what I really need.